# Show, that each connected graph contains a walk which contains each edge exactly twice. Is it a closed walk

Tags: graph-theory

I am doing some practice for graphs and was stuck at the question
"Show, that each connected graph contains a walk
which contains each edge exactly twice. Is it a closed
walk?", does anyone know how to prove this. I already know it is close to the proof for CET(closed euler trail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A walk exists if there are 2 or fewer vertices of odd degree.  And a closed walk exists if all vertices have even degree.

If you walk every edge twice, you could take your original graph and make a new graph with two parallel edges in the new graph every place there was an edge in the old graph.  Every vertex has an even degree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more explicit way (although a bit messily stated at this time) to prove it such that we get a closed walk.

Assume first that we work with a tree. Start at some node $v$. Then each edge out from that node lead to subtrees. For each subtree, move out to it, do a closed walk using each edge twice within that subtree, and return to $v$. In essence, we do depth-first transversal on each subtree.

If we don't work on a tree, consider the following tweak of the above algorithm: When encountering a vertex during DFS, consider the edges going out from it that haven't already been traversed. While any two of these may be connected by some cycle of unused edges in the graph, take one of them and go "back and forth" on it, thus using it twice. When no more unused edges may be connected via cycles in such a manner, resume the DFS.

The above tweak works since we force a "local subtree-like structure" around every node, so that every "subtree" will be covered by the DFS before returning to any previous "parent" nodes.